MariaDB syntax error near: 'READ ONLY = 1'
I'm currently learning MariaDB basics and one of the problems I've encountered is this syntax error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'READ ONLY = 1' at line 1

after entering this command:
ALTER DATABASE testDB READ ONLY = 1;

Can anyone help? I don't know what's going on.

There is a MariaDB Feature request for this MDEV-17476. Please watch, vote and/or implement this and it will be raised in priority.

The READ ONLY option was added to MySQL for the 8.0 release.
But MySQL and MariaDB are diverging. This option is not part of MariaDB and will not work there.
MariaDB does have a --read_only command line/config file system variable when starting the service, but that would not be just the one database. It does at least show dynamic support, so I would expect to be able to change it for a running system via the SET GLOBAL command:
SET GLOBAL read_only={OFF|ON}


The syntax of MariaDB's ALTER DATABASE is documented to be
ALTER {DATABASE | SCHEMA} [db_name]
    alter_specification ...
ALTER {DATABASE | SCHEMA} db_name
    UPGRADE DATA DIRECTORY NAME

alter_specification:
    [DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET [=] charset_name
  | [DEFAULT] COLLATE [=] collation_name
  | COMMENT [=] 'comment'

Your query doesn't comply with the recognized syntax. You appear to be using a query designed for another database (such as MySQL).
